# Need tricky Wpf layout

Tags: wpf, layout, resize, width

[image: Layout illustration]

I need a layout that when I decrease window width by moving it's right edge, firstly gray part's width decreasing to 0, and only after that white part's width decreasing starts.
I tried to do it using DockPanel and Grid but without success.

UPDATE:
The width of the white part depends on user data and cannot be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last element in a DockPanel will span to available space. Not so tricky after all.

```
<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <DockPanel Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock Text="Element 1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Element 2"/>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="Element N" MinWidth="100"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Element with variable width, can be less than text"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a fixed width on the white part, and set the grey part to a dynamic width.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ...
</Grid>
```

This however will not dynamically resize the first column's width when the width of the `Window` becomes less than 500. Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but it's a start.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't fix a width, it depends on user data, I can only limit Min and Max width.